# How do I vertically center the cursor in this text area?

Tags: html, css, textarea

I have read through many posts and tried many methods, including adding a line-height attribute, but I cannot seem to get the cursor in this textarea to be vertically centered.

It is important that the position remains absolute. Here is the CSS for the textarea:

```
.tile-text-input {
    height: 23%;
    width: 70%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 30%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var textInput = document.getElementById('textInput');
var textDuplicate = document.getElementById('textDuplicate');

textInput.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
 textDuplicate.innerHTML = textInput.value;
});
```

```css
#img-wrapper {
 width: 400px;
 height: 350px;
 background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553095066-5014bc7b7f2d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8d2FsbCUyMGJhY2tncm91bmR8ZW58MHx8MHx8&w=1000&q=80');
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}

#textDuplicate { 
color: #fff; 
text-align: center;
padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textInput"></textarea>

<div id="img-wrapper">
<span id="textDuplicate"></span>
</div>
```

Can I ask why you are trying to do this? There is not an out of the box way to do it by just setting an attribute. So you would probably need to use javascript to somehow measure the height of the textarea or content, or use a content editable div and duplicate what the user types inside a hidden textarea which is a huge accessibility issue. I honestly would avoid this.

Comment: The input text will become a caption over an image, which will be centered. I want the text in the input to match the final display of the caption, if possible, so that the transition from input to display appears seamless. That was my thought at least, but maybe it's not worth it.

Comment: So just to make sure I am correct you are essentially trying to make it so that what the user types overlays onto an image? If so, I would save yourself the hassle and just have a textarea or input the user can type in and use some JS or jQuery to simply take what the user types into the field and make a div that overlays the image with a paragraph or span and use flexbox to vertically center it over the image.

Comment: After the user saves the input, the input is hidden and replaced with a div that has the same style/positioning, so that it appears seamless. I am having trouble getting the text vertically centered in the div as well, perhaps because of the fixed position or the height/width based on % of the parent div? But those are things I can't really change. I am using javascript.

Comment: @ragmats I updated my answer to give you something to go off of. It has a textarea that when text is entered will duplicate into a span that is vertically and horizontally centered inside the div with a background-image. From there you can add more spans and inputs and just tie them together.